# How to show load spinner for particular div content load instead of whole page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have some web page to fetch the user related data and huge count of images. The problem is while load the page it took more time due to images , Images are rendered in separate div in the page. So i want loader spinner for that particular div.

Note: I know how to implement for page load. Just need for particular div.

Just look the below my implementation idea.

```
<body>
<div id="divUserContent">
</div>
<div id="divuserimages">
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the parent element to the loading element has a position set to relative. See this example below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.loading-container {
  padding: 10rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative; /* this keeps .loading-text inside it */
  width: 5rem;
}

.loading-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -9px; /* take .loading-text height, divide by -2 */
  margin-left: -35px; /* take .loading-text width, dividide by -2*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loading-container">
    <div class="loading-text">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it should not stop the page load right ? I mean other content will loaded expect the image div ? So loader will be showing on ONLY image div